# Get last letter from arabic string Php

Tags: php, string, utf-8, arabic

I've been working with Arabic characters for a while now. 
Look at this:

```
$string = "السلام";
```

Works perfectly when I print it.

But. I want to get the last letter, "م".
I've tried

```
$string[strlen($string]-1)];
```

Tried substring too.

Getting this output: �

SOLVED: 
Forgot to add: mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to use byte-type operations on a multi-byte string (utf-8? -16?) You need to use the mb_*() functions to work with multi-byte strings: http://php.net/mb_substr

Comment: Sorry, that what i've tried wrote strlen by mistake, same result.

Comment: mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8"); Forgot that one.

Comment: I don't think PHP supports RTL languages anyways. a string's purely LTR in PHP's internal representation. `mb_substr($str, 0, 1)` is probably what you really want.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<?php
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
$string = "السلام";
echo mb_substr($string, -1);
?>
```

Your code is also not correct (there is syntax error):

```
$string[strlen($string]-1)];
                      ^--should be )

$string[strlen($string)-1)];
```

Comment: Thanks, mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8"); that's exactly what i forgot

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`mb_strlen`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php) for multibyte strings. These characters take more than one byte, therefore when you fetch them with native non-mb functions, you take only one part of the character, which is usually some gibberish. [`mb_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php) functions take care of that.

Comment: @Cthulhu - I see Cthulhu's army is conquering the world ;)